# Direct OnClick based off of your OS

Tags: javascript, redirect

I am having an issue where essentially what we want to do is when the user clicks the button it will redirect them to a certain page depending on what their OS is(ex. iOS, android, etc)

I just cannot seem to get any of the actions working and not sure where I am going wrong.

```
    <button onclick="OsAction()" id="button">
      Click me to download
    </button>

    <script>
 function DetectOs(){

    var OSName="Unknown OS";
if (navigator.platform.indexOf("Win")!=-1) OSName="Windows";
if (navigator.platform.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MacOS";
if (navigator.platform.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";
if (navigator.platform.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux";
if (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPhone")!=-1) OSName="iOS";
if (navigator.platform.indexOf("Android")!=-1) OSName="Android";
   document.write('Your OS: '+OSName);
 }

        function OsAction(){      
      document.getElementByID('button').onClick = function(){
        if (OSName === "iOS"){
      window.location.href = 'https://apple.com'
      } 
      else{

      window.location.href = 'https://google.com'

     };

      }
      };

    </script>
```

Any assistance would be gladly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems:

1. You never call `DetectOs()`
2. `OSName` is a local variable within `DetectOS()`, because it's declared with `var`. So `OsAction()` can't access the variable.
3. `OsAction()` doesn't actually redirect the page. It just adds a new click handler that will redirect the *next* time you click on the button. There's no need to assign `onclick` inside a function that's being run from `onclick`.

Or you could have `DetectOs()` return the value, and call it from `OsAction()`.

```js
function DetectOs() {

  var OSName = "Unknown OS";
  if (navigator.platform.indexOf("Win") != -1) OSName = "Windows";
  if (navigator.platform.indexOf("Mac") != -1) OSName = "MacOS";
  if (navigator.platform.indexOf("X11") != -1) OSName = "UNIX";
  if (navigator.platform.indexOf("Linux") != -1) OSName = "Linux";
  if (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPhone") != -1) OSName = "iOS";
  if (navigator.platform.indexOf("Android") != -1) OSName = "Android";
  return OSName;
}

function OsAction() {
  var OSName = DetectOs();
  if (OSName === "iOS") {
    window.location.href = 'https://apple.com'
  } else {
    window.location.href = 'https://google.com'
  }
};
```

```html
<button onclick="OsAction()" id="button">
  Click me to download
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function DetectOs(){
 var OSName="Unknown OS";
 if (navigator.platform.indexOf("Win")!=-1) OSName="Windows";
 if (navigator.platform.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MacOS";
 if (navigator.platform.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";
 if (navigator.platform.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux";
 if (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPhone")!=-1) OSName="iOS";
 if (navigator.platform.indexOf("Android")!=-1) OSName="Android";
 return OSName;
}
document.getElementByID('button').onClick = function(){
   var OSName = DetectOs();
   if (OSName === "iOS"){
      window.location.href = 'https://apple.com'
   } else {
      window.location.href = 'https://google.com'
   }
};
```

You dont need to use the function OsAction(). try removing it like so.

And also from the button

```
<button id="button">
  Click me to download
</button>
```